# Not retrieving new data after setting Firebase Persistence Enabled to true?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After making `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` When  query   to get data

```
Query  query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                      .getReference()
                      .child("notifications")
                      .child("entities")
                      .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString())
                      .orderByChild("seen")
                      .equalTo(0);
```

From [data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g74qS.png)

it gives old data that is in cache instead of  new changed data in Firebase databse.But When I change  `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` to `setPersistenceEnabled(false)` then everything is fine **While** I also want firebase data to be persisted in cache and also change When change is made to Firebase database.Please help to **maintain Firebase data persistence** along with **realtime change**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using:

```
setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

It means that you'll be able to query your the database even if you are offline. This is happening because Firebase creates a local copy of your database that will persist after your app/device restarts. Every change that is made while you are offline, will be updated on Firebase servers once you are back online. To be more clear, every client that is using a Firebase database and uses `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` maintains it's own internal (local) version of the database. When data is updated, it is first written to this local version of the database.

So, by enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime database client would sync while online, persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This means that your app will work as it would be online by using the local data stored in the cache.

But, there is no way to stop the retrieval of the data from the cache while you are not connected to the server, as you cannot force the retrieval of the data from the cache while you're connected to the server and unfortunately this behaviour cannot be changed.

Comment: Sir! I have coded it for a back end service that keeps on monitoring state of nodes on seen property  with some Thread sleep time and even if I restart it (with  persistence  true  )  is not getting  what it should get in synchronized way.

Comment: That's correct. If you `setPersistenceEnabled(true);` and you are offline, when restarting the app, you'll get the data from the cache. If you want to get data from the server, you just need to go online, that's it. Have you understood now?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your conceptual  guide.

Comment: Sir! As I have asked that question after facing an issue that app is not getting new copy of data  while it is online as I have a service that is running continuously to monitor sate of nodes.Your answer only suggests  an 'unfortunate phenomena' about firebase.

Comment: While you are online, you cannot see the data from the cache but be sure once you are back online, the data from your cache will be synchronized on Firebase servers. If you think that is a but, you can report it to the Firebase support team. But "unfortunate phenomena"? This is the normal behaviour, this is how it works.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Comment: I solve my problem by restarting back-end service  by registering a broad cast receiver When device goes online then It  works fine for me.Since problem was that service keep on running either user is online or not to monitor data  and never restarts but as I make that broadcast receiver mechanism to restart it when device comes online then works fine.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Do you think that my answer was helpful?

Comment: Yes your answer was helpful since it teaches me that I have to restart my service(in your answer second line of  first paragraph) when device comes online.