# How to enable firebase persistence for a specific reference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

In my Android app I have the followings `DatabaseReference:`

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
DatabaseReference articlesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Articles");
```

I want to enable data persistence just for `usersRef`. I have enabled persistence with the following line... (It keeps all my database)

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Is there any way to enable it just for a reference? Help! Please...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047550/firebase-android-only-need-specific-table-to-be-in-local-device/54050310#54050310

Answer (score 0):

Persistence can only be configured for the entire database.  There is no per-reference configuration.  You might want to establish your own cache for that instead.